# Travel time not automatically generated in Calenders

Tags: calendar, macos

I have just installed Mac OS X Mavericks and have been familiarising myself with some of the new features. One of the touted features was the ability to tell you the "travel time" for any given appointment. However when adding a new event to my calendar, the travel time is just specified times that I set, it will not show me how long it will take via car for example.

I have ensured that Calendars is allowed to use my current location, as well as Maps (which I believe is used to generate the time).

Answer (score 2):

Try reentering the address so that Calendar registers it as an address (addresses will be suggested to you when as you type) rather than a mere string - that worked for me.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, the address is a real address that I've used before to route on my iPhone, its stored in my contacts.

Comment: If you open one of these events do you see a map at the bottom? If not that suggests that Calendar hasn't recognised your address. In which case it won't provide estimated travel times.